Prove that a functional equation has at least one root
Let $f$ be a strictly increasing and continuous function that satisfies the equality $$f^3(x)+βf^2(x)+γf(x)=x^3-2x^2+6x-1, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}
$$ with $β,γ\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $β^2<3γ$
Prove that the equation $f(x)=0$ has at least one real solution in $(0,1)$
My attempt
$$f^3(0)+βf^2(0)+γf(0)=-1\\f^3(1)+βf^2(1)+γf(1)=4$$
Then Let $g(x)=x^3+βx^2+γx$ and $g(f(0))=-1$ , $g(f(1))=4$ .And $g$ is continuous so by the intermediate value theorem there exists an $x_0\in (f(0),f(1))$ s.t $g(x_0)=0$, so
$$x_0^3+βx_2^2+γx=0\iff x_0(x_0^2+βx_0+γ)=0$$
So either $x_0=0$ or $x_0^2+βx_0+γ$ which cannot be true since $β^2<3γ$
I cannot continue from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Apply intermediate value theorem to $g \circ f$. This gives $x_1$ such that $g(f(x_1)) =0$. From the computation at the end of your question you can see that $f(x_1) = x_0 = 0$.

$f^2(x)$ might be confused for $f(f(x))$.

First of all we need to define $g\circ$$f:[0,1]\rightarrow[-1,4]$ where $g(x)$=$x^3$+$\beta$$x^2$+$\gamma$$x$ just as you did. Now we can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem since the defined interval is closed and the function is continous. Then we now by the IVT that $\exists$$x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $g\circ$$f(x_0)=0$.Now look at $g(x)=(x)\cdot(x^2+\beta{x}+\gamma )$. Then observe the $\Delta$ for the quadratic part of $g(x)$,
$   \Delta=\frac{-\beta\pm \sqrt{\beta^2-4\gamma}}{2}$
We know that $\beta^2<3\gamma$ hence inside the square root is negative which tells us we have no reel roots from that part. Finally we know we have a $x_0$ such that $g\circ{f}(x_0)=0$ so,  if $g(f(x_0))=0$ then $f(x_0)=0$ since g has no other reel roots.Hence we have a root for $f(x)$ and that root $x_0$ is in the interval $(0,1)$.
